# Django rest framework 401 error with React Axios

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

Im working on a project with Django rest framework backend and React as frontend. Axios is used for http request and JWT for authentication. I issue im facing is that, after login and getting token django is throwing 401 error for every request. But this issue is resolved if header config is toggled for Axios.

Please find the below codes for your reference and help to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

```
DRF **settings.py**

 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
      'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
 )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=2),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,
}


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:3000"
]

**axios setup**


const axiosClient = axios.create({
baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
});

export default axiosClient;

const jToken = useSelector((state) => state.authSlice.accessToken);
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${jToken}`;
 return config;
});


**Axios request**

const fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await axiosClient.get(AppContext.managementStudentUri);
  //   console.log(response.data);
  setData(response.data);
  setIsLoading(false);
} catch (error) {
  apiErrorHandler(error);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this issue is resolved if header config is toggled for Axios.

The token is used for Authentification so once Login is done and token is generated, it should be sent with every request to identify the use.

But if it's not sent Django throws a 401 Unauthorized Error

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: **Make Sure Tokens Are Ready on Time**
When getting the token from Redux using useSelector, ensure it's all set before sending your API request. Use tools like Redux Thunk to manage timing issues that could lead to the token not being ready when needed.

Step 2: **Get the Interceptor Order Right**
The interceptor that attaches your token to the request header should come before the one that handles the requests. This guarantees your token is included when you're sending data to the server.

Step 3: **Check Token Validity and Secret Key**
Check that your token is still valid and hasn't expired. Also, double-check that the secret key used to make and verify tokens is the same in your Django settings and during login.

Step 4: **Verify Your CORS Setup**
Ensure that your Django server is okay with requests coming from your React frontend's domain. Adjust your server's CORS settings to include your front end's origin.

Step 5: **Dive into Logging and Network Checks**
Turn on detailed logging on both your front end and back end. Your browser's network tab is a great detective tool: it lets you see precisely what headers are being sent and what the server is replying with. This can pinpoint where the communication might be going wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).